# Есть ли готовые продукты для организации сервера на Java?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, java

Существуют ли в продаже готовых продуктов для организации socket соединения в Java? Желания разрабатывать свой велосипед нету, очень бы хотелось найти готовый вариант, который будет стабильно держать соединение, работать с потоками и желательно шифровать данные. Было бы идеально, если бы еще были плагины для клиентской части (например, на C или AS3).

А также по какому запросу можно найти подобное? Потому что на запросы buy java socket server по большинству идут на форумы программирования.

Comment: А стандартные [SSLSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) и родная для Java многопоточность чем не устраивают?

Comment: Посмотрите http://netty.io/

Comment: > Потому что на запросы buy java socket server по большинству идут на форумы программирования

Потому, что вы не представляете, насколько это нелепо звучит.

Comment: Ну по ключевым словам по сути что-то нужное должно было получиться)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C плагинами (as3) и JAVA навскидку только SmartFox:

[SmartFox](http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/)

Еще с плагином Photon но он на C#/C++:

[Photon](http://doc.exitgames.com/en/onpremise/current/getting-started/photon-server-intro)

Больше вменяемых не помню.

Вроде RED5 на JAVA, но он работает через RTMP протокол.